# Bootstrap Set Up Errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined & Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a bootstrap template.  I am getting two errors, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  When I search for similar issues, it seems to be the scripts are out of order, but I think they are correctly positioned.

THE TWO ERRORS:

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!--IE Edge meta Tag-->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!--Viewport-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!--Minified Bootstrap CSS from MaxCDN-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">

<title>Bootstrap 3.3.5</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords, go, here">
<meta name="description" content="meta description goes here">
</head>

<body>
<h1>header</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an numquam platonem abhorreant mea, nec at eripuit tincidunt accommodare. Ut sit utinam ridens commune. Nec ad stet utroque periculis. Eu eum errem assueverit. Ius vitae definitionem ea.</p>

<!--jquery CDN-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap's JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--link to local js file-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, you should link the jQuery lib not jQuery UI )

Just add this code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

got from here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error. You need jQuery to be referenced first, then Bootstrap CSS, then you need boostrap js. **You have jQuery UI, but not the jQuery JS file**. To use jQuery UI, you need both jQuery normal file and then the UI file

List in order like this:

1. Bootstrap CSS file
2. Your CSS file
3. jQuery js lib
4. Bootstrap js lib
5. jQuery UI js lib

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI is built on top of jQuery so you will need to include jQuery as well.

```
<!--jquery CDN-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap's JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: isn't that this: <!--jquery CDN-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: <!--jquery CDN--> is just a HTML comment, it won't actually fetch the jQuery library. You need to replace it with the line I've added.